# How do i keep the tail zero in my dataframe and avoid variable lengths differ error from R

Tags: r, zero, variable-length

I have a dataset like below:-

| Location | Reading |
| --- | --- |
| Above | 0.0370 |
| Above | 0.0261 |
| Below | 0.0660 |
| Above | 0.0420 |

now when I load this in R, it appears prefectly in the console but when I run the below script-

```
model <- aov(Reading ~ Belmopan)
```

it gives

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Reading ~ Belmopan, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Belmopan')
```

when i open the `.csv` file again, the "0"s were removed.

Can you please tell me what should I do ?

thanks,

Comment: What is `Belmopan`  It is not a column in the data you showed?   whereas your column name is `Location`

Comment: With the posted data `aov(Reading ~ Location, df2)` works without errors. VTC as not reproducible.

Comment: apologise, it is the "Location"